# What is the reason behind preventing creation of custom Window classes if they explicitly specify where content should go?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, inheritance

So, the goal is to create a new custom window in XAML (with things in it), that I can use in another XAML designer as the **root node** (and the workaround is to do [this](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.gr/2009/09/user-control-inheritance-in-wpf.html)). This used to make it possible (and there are a [number](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/creating-a-base-window-class-in-wpf) [of](http://hardcodedblog.blogspot.gr/2009/12/making-custom-windows-in-wpf.html) [resources](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx) still out there mistakenly saying as much), but was changed and will now get you the error: "xyz cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML".

Microsoft tersely [states](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957231):

> You need to define your base class all in code without using XAML.

This is further explained by others that it is because the XAML designer would not know where to put content in the custom window; which is reasonable, as there are things in its ContentControl already.

So, that got me thinking.

If I create my custom MyWindow in xaml like so:

```
<Window x:Class="MyStuff.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MyWindow">
    <Grid>
        <UserControl Name="ContentContainer"/>
        <!-- some undefined content here to justify this exercise -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in code, hide the Window's content and point it to a new empty [System.Windows.ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) (the UserControl's ContentControl in this example):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyStuff
{
    public partial class MyWindow : System.Windows.Window 
    {
        // hide our window content with new keyword
        public new object Content 
        {
            get { return ContentContainer.Content; }
            set { ContentContainer.Content = value; }
        }

        public Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

...Why am I still forbidden from doing this?
Why is the default compiler behavior not to require Content to be explicitly overwritten to point to another suitable location in this circumstance?

And in implementations which do not define where content should go explicitly, why not have the default functionality be to replace whatever is in the ContentControl in the parent control as content with a warning anyway (and only throw an error when the parent window's ContentControl is inaccessible)?

Comment: Why not simply define a new ControlTemplate for the `Window` class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa969824(v=vs.85).aspx Just add your controls around the ContentPresenter, and there you go... A reusable XAML for all the Windows you want.

Comment: Why not indeed? This is the second suggested solution in the link in the second line of the question, and likely the one I will be going with. 

Thanks for the comment though, I hope we can save others with this problem a little time in future.

Comment: I see, I hadn't checked that link :P In my opinion, modifying the template should be the first option for this kind of things, even if what you were trying to do was actually supported. Controls in WPF are supposed to be lookless, and their visual representation come only from Styles and Templates. Window is a Control, extending it and trying to define a fixed look in code goes against WPF principles. The correct way is through Templates; ControlTemplate, in this case, since what you're trying to modify is not the Window's contents template but the Window's look itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting mixed up with what content *actually is*.

The `Content` of the window is everything inside the window element, this **includes** your `UserControl`.

There are a few options for you.

1. Create a dependency property for **additional content** and have a `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter` bind to this property. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx).
2. Create a `Style` for your `Window`, where you can define what *goes around* the `Content` of the `Window` using a `ControlTemplate`. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/12/27/wpf-control-templates-an-overview.aspx).
3. A combination of both 1 and 2, which would be a **Custom Control**, here you will inherit from `Window`, and define it's style and control template. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just hoping you could hide the content property of an element in the same way as other ones (by creating a getter and setter, and thus extend the functionality).

Thank you for the suggestions. They are useful and will help people who are stuck on this problem, although I am still curious as to why this was Microsoft's chosen functionality when I can envisage ways that seem more reasonable to go about it then an adamant build error.